# How to setup (2) level of custom define type in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am still relative new to c#, so please be gentle on me thanks.
I am trying to create a user defined type of 2 layer array ie. My goal is to get something like

```
     level1[i].level2[j].level3 = "abc";
```

How should i define it?
How should i initialize it?

I have the code which works on 1 level, but I fail to do it in 2 levels.

can you post some working snippet of code please? i couldn't find anything like this on the internet.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: i think my questions is too general, but my code is too long to post all out, my final solution uses more variables to hold my data.

Comment: _"i have the code which works on 1 level,..."_ Where? It could help us to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you talking about Multidimensional Array ??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe can solve your problem:

```
Dictionary<iType, Dictionary<jType, TypeOfYourClassToStore>> dict;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a two dimensional array.

```
String[,] x = new String[10, 10];
x[0, 0] = "a";
x[0, 1] = "b";
//...
```

Comment: well i can do it, but the data structures gets ugly, because my user defined type has many different variable, if i use a 2D array, then i have to setup another UDT for it, that means more variable and i cannot confine it into 1 UDT